# The Accessibility Object for AS2 is returning a false positive with IE10 on Win 8 Pro. How do I correct this?

Tags: windows-8, actionscript, actionscript-2, accessibility, internet-explorer-10

There is an issue with the our legacy content player, which is written in Flash Actionscript 1 & 2.  This player behaves fine in most browsers on most platforms, but in IE10 on Windows 8 it doesn't work properly.

Internet Explorer 10
Version:  10.0.9200.16688
Update Version:  10.0.9 (KB2870699)

Windows 8 Pro

This seems to because of the Flash engine's Accessibility object using the Microsoft Active
Accessibility (MSAA) API to detect the presence of Screen Readers.  This detection is creating a false positive on Windows 8 machines and that may be due to the touch screen support on that platform.  This doesn't appear to be occuring with Chrome or Firefox on the same platform; however.  So I suspect that IE or IE's Flash compenent is doing something different than these other browsers.